# This is the second SPOJ Prime Generator ? Can anyone explain why it says wrong answer?

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main(void) {
int tc=0,start=0,end=0,i=1,n=0,j=0;
char t[3],s[11],e[11];
scanf("%s",&t);
tc=atoi(t);
for(i=1;i<=tc;i++){
    scanf("%s %s",&s,&e);
    start=atoi(s);
    end=atoi(e);
    for(n = start;n <= end;n++){
        if(n==1) continue;
        if(n==2 || n==3) printf("%d\n",n);
        if(n%2==0 || n%3==0){
            continue;
        }
        for(j = 5; j * j < n; j+=6){
            if(n % j == 0 || n % (j+2) == 0){
                continue;
            }
        }
        printf("%d\n",n);
    }
    if(i!=tc)
    printf("\n");
}
return 0;
}
```

P.S. I am not good at C but I implemented same program in Python and it was exceeding time limit. I would also like to know whether this problem can be done efficiently in Python.

Comment: Add a comments in your program, so that program can be analysed and understood.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Few points:

1) For taking input as integer use `scanf("%d",&tc)` instead of

```
scanf("%s",&t);
tc=atoi(t);
```

2) Replace your inner loop with the code I pasted below. Your inner loop doesn't check for multiples of 5. Like 5,55,95...

Simple algorithm is to check whether number has any factor till sqrt(n). If yes, then it is composite number else prime.

`for(n = start;n <= end;n++){
        if(n==1) continue;
        int flag=1;
        for(j=2;j*j<=n;j++){
            if(n%j==0){
                flag=0;     //Is a factor
                break;
            }
        }
        if(flag)
        printf("%d\n",n);
    }`